# Using Volumes to reveal secret doors in UE4 C++ project

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I'm working on a maze project and I would like to have secret doors. My basic idea is to have the walls be destroyed when the player is both within the bounds of a trigger volume, and presses a button. I know the basic way to implement the code, but my main concern is how to handle the volumes. Should I create a class, maybe called "SecretController" that holds the code that says:

"if player is in box[i] and presses fire, destroy door[i]"

This seems like it would work, but I'd rather know before I go create a ton of stuff I'll just have to delete later. Thanks for the help folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan is sound. As to script complexity, this would be a tiny amount of blueprint nodes: one bool for volume, one bool for button, and boolean AND node, a branch node, a Destroy node. That should get you running.

I mention Blueprint because, although you have a C++ proejct, Blueprint has a much faster iteration time and was designed specifically for prototyping gameplay. When it works how you want, *then* transfer it to code.

Comment: Sounds good, I will follow that method. Thank you JonS.